# Pull certain elements out of a 2D python list?

Tags: python, list, testing

As an easy way to test for the correct way to pull out certain elements of a large tileset, inputted as a  2D list in my program, I put the following into the Python Shell:

```
->>>test = [ [1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9] ]
```

and upon trying to test it out, I got this:

```
->>>test1 = test[:][2]

->>>test1

[7, 8, 9]
```

from inputting `test[:][2]` I expected test1 to return `[3,6,9]`

Can someone explain to me why I got `[7,8,9]` instead?

Also, if you could explain how I would get the output of `[3,6,9]` ? I know that I could just say the following:

```
>>>test1 = [ test[0][2], test[1][2], test[2][2] ]
```

but if I wrote it in context of my program, that line would be WAY longer and harder to maintain.  If there is an easier way to get `[3,6,9]` than from the way I listed just above, I would highly appreciate some insight into getting that.

Answer (score 5):

for standard python, you can do this:

```
>>> test = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
>>> [x[2] for x in test]
[3, 6, 9]
>>>
```

as for `test1 = test[:][2]`, it's because `test[:]` just equals to `test` (**edit:** *actually, it's exact copy of `test` and not the same list*)

also take a look at [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) library.

Comment: More specifically, `test[:]` is a *copy* of `test`, not just a reference... for example, if you did `a = test`, `a` and `test` would still refer to the same list, but with `a = test[:]`, `a` and `test` now refer to different lists.

Comment: yes you right, forgot to mention that, I've meant that for user purposes it effectively equals test :)

Comment: I hate it when people nit-pick my answers, so sorry about that :)  I just thought that in this particular case it might be useful to explain why this notation existed in the first place.

Comment: no prob, actually it makes my answer better so it's for good :)

Comment: I was under the impression that using a colin(:) in a list allowed you to cycle through values in that list. by saying test[:][2], I thought that would cycle through each third sub-element of each element of test.  Should I have said something like test[1:][2] instead?

Comment: The colon is a slicing notation, and using a bare colon returns a slice of the whole list.  You can see this more clearly if you use parenthesis to show the order of operations: `(test[:])[2]`.  You are just getting the third element of a copy of the original list.  Therefore, `test[1:][2] => (test[1:])[2]` and would raise an IndexError because `test[1:]` would return a two-element list (`[ [4,5,6],[7,8,9] ]`).

Answer (score 0):

`test[:]` returns a copy of `test`, so `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]`. So `test[:][2]` is `[7,8,9]`.
Using list comprehesion you can get what you want easily:

```
>>> [x[2] for x in test]
[3, 6, 9]
```

Comment: I don't entirely understand how that syntax works, but I've seen weird stuff like that before. I probably would have written that more like for x in test: print x[2]